# C# combobox like dropdown list in web application

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have comboBox component and i am adding items like `comboBox1.Items.Add("Item1")`. But i alo need to know some other info about this Item. So if i click "Item1" i need to get `"102454"`. 
Can i somehow save 102454 to "Item1" on combobox.

At web aplication there is dropdown list which look like

```
<select>
  <option value="102454">Item1</option>
</select>
```

and when i click "Item1" i get `102454`.

Can i do this in windows desktop applicatin with combobox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit** better solution:

Use a `KeyValuePair` and `ValueMember` \ `DisplayValue`:

```
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Key";
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Value";

comboBox1.Items.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(102454, "Item1"));
```

As Kristian points out this can be extended to be even more flexible - you can put whatever object you like into the list of items, and set the value and display members on the combobox to be whatever property path you want.

---

To get the key back later you can do this:

```
var item = combobox1.SelectedItem;

int key = ((KeyValuePair<int, string>)item).Key;
```

Comment: This is the most flexible solution. As the "KeyValuePair" can be changed with any object. If you use e.g. "Person" as the object, you can set: 
comboBox1.ValueMember = "SSN";
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";

Comment: thx will try. but right code is KeyValuePair<int, string>(102454, "Item1")

Comment: hmm how can i get now Key back. I can not read 102454 or can i?

Comment: @senzacionale Updated my answer to show how to get the `Key` back out

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at the [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem.aspx) property.

Answer (score 0):

A have created a similar class like Mark Pim suggested; however, mine uses generics.
I certainly would not choose to make the Value property a string type.

```
    public class ListItem<TKey> : IComparable<ListItem<TKey>>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the data that is associated with this ListItem instance.
        /// </summary>
        public TKey Key
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the description that must be shown for this ListItem.
        /// </summary>
        public string Description
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the ListItem class
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key"></param>
        /// <param name="description"></param>
        public ListItem( TKey key, string description )
        {
            this.Key = key;
            this.Description = description;
        }

        public int CompareTo( ListItem<TKey> other )
        {
            return Comparer<String>.Default.Compare (Description, other.Description);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.Description;
        }
    }
```

It is also easy to create a non-generic variant of it:

```
    public class ListItem : ListItem<object>
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ListItem"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key"></param>
        /// <param name="description"></param>
        public ListItem( object key, string description )
            : base (key, description)
        {
        }
    }
```